# How to set the new object in TableView, swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, master-detail

My task is to do something like `MasterDetailApplication`, when I press button(`firstViewController`) current date should be saved in my `tableView`(`secondViewController`). And when I do this the new date should be above the last one. `MasterDetailApplication` works like this what I want but there is the button in the same `tableVieController`. I think I should use `atIndex : 0` but I don't know how to use it.

```
Parameters.swift:
import UIKit


var param: Parameters = Parameters()



struct data{
    var timer = NSString()
}


class Parameters: NSObject {

   var datas = [data]()

    func passingData(timer: NSString)
    {
        datas.append(data(timer: timer))
    }
}


ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = 0
    var timer = NSTimer()
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        counterLabel.text = String(counter)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,target:self, selector: ("update"),userInfo: nil, repeats :true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func update(){
        counterLabel.text = String(++counter)
        if counter == 50 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }


    @IBAction func pressedButton(sender: UIButton) {
        param.passingData(counterLabel.text!)
    }

}


TableViewController.swift:

import UIKit


class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var data = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
/*
    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        data.insertObject(NSDate(), atIndex: 0)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
    */

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return param.datas.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("default", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let date = NSDateFormatter()
    date.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\nhh:mm:ss"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = param.datas[indexPath.row].timer
    cell.textLabel.text = "\(date.stringFromDate(NSDate()))"
    return cell

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to viewDidLoad

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
```

Add this to your MasterViewController

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    objects.insertObject(NSDate(), atIndex: 0)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

This is the boiler plate code for editing-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            objects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }
```

This is what you get when you create default master-view application in Xcode. If you want to have this date passed to the SecondViewController you will need to send this date in PrepareforSegue function. You save this date in your ivar of secondviewcontroller. Then once you have you can create a cell like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
        cell.textLabel.text = object.description
        return cell
    }
```

If you add all this to your Master it will work but then if you need this date in SecondViewController. Save date as your ivar(SecondViewController) once user clicks on a row in Master. Use prepareForSegue to provide the date to DestinationViewController.

Comment: Actually I know how to do MasterDetailApplication but look i have ViewController and TableViewController. When I press button in ViewController I move to the TableViewController and then my information have been saved in table. My problem is how to do this when I back from my TableViewController and press again button and a new information is saved above the last one. I am at the stage when I press the button I move to the TableViewController and my data is saved in tableView but when I do this again my new data is saved under the old data. How to change it?

Comment: In MasterDetailApplication this situation works fine. New informations are saved above the old one. And I think this line of code is responisble for this: (NSDate(), atIndex: 0). How can I put it to my code?

Comment: Create a private array in tableViewController. Inserting data in that array should be always at index 0. Dont append to the array. Use insert at index 0.